# A column cannot be stored without storing other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `ServiceTask` with columns `serviceno`, `taskno`, `time_spent`, and `mechaniccode`.

`serviceno` and `taskno` is the PK, mechaniccode is FK references to `Mechanic` table
Assume that, when I insert data, the mechaniccode is exist in table `Mechanic`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO ServiceTask VALUES('0001','0002',3,NULL)
```

It should error because the `mechaniccode` is NULL.

How can I do this in T-SQL:

> For each service task the time spent cannot be stored without storing the mechanic

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how to make the field not `null` or do you mean ref integrity, since you call one `mechanic` and the field is `mechaniccode`?

Comment: so time_spent should be null if mechaniccode is null, and time_spent should not be null if mechaniccode is not null ?

Comment: @christiandev I mean storing the mechanic is storing to the field mechaniccode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to add a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ServiceTask
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckOnlyTimespentWithMechanic
CHECK (
(CASE WHEN time_spent IS NOT NULL AND mechaniccode IS NULL 
      THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) = 1)  
GO

INSERT INTO ServiceTask VALUES(1,2,NULL,1) -- allowed
INSERT INTO ServiceTask VALUES(1,2,3,NULL) -- not allowded
```

Result:

> Schema Creation Failed: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK
>   constraint "CheckOnlyTimespentWithMechanic". The conflict occurred in
>   database "db_6_2319a", table "dbo.ServiceTask".:

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions about your datatypes, nullability and that you don't need to do anything with `serviceno` or `taskno`, you could add a check constraint which checks that either `time_spent` is null or 0, or if `time_spent` is more than 0, that mechanic is populated:

```
ALTER TABLE ServiceTask
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_mechanic CHECK 
(time_spent IS NULL 
     OR time_spent = 0
     OR (time_spent > 0 AND mechaniccode IS NOT NULL))
```

You may not need all of these checks, dependant on whether `time_spent` allows nulls or not.